How to change the timeout for an inquiry command
I'm getting timeouts on inquiry while a write buffer is active because the device cannot respond to the inquiry until the write buffer is complete.
See errors .
Dec 10 16:04:39 soul kernel: sd 0:0:34:0: [sdai] tag#2540 CDB: Inquiry 12 01 83 00 fe 00   Done: TIMEOUT_ERROR  
Dec 10 16:04:39 soul kernel: sd 0:0:34:0: attempting task abort!scmd(0x000000005af3d755), outstanding for 7050 ms & timeout 7000 ms 
Dec 10 16:04:39 soul kernel: sd 0:0:34:0: task abort: SUCCESS scmd(0x000000005af3d755) 

it appears that inquiry has a 7 sec timeout; I was only aware of a single timeout control of
/sys/block/sdac/device/timeout 44

Is there a way to change the timeout for inquiry ?
